# How to turn OFF IDENTITY_INSERT for GORM

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

I would like to turn OFF the `IDENTITY_INSERT` to insert data with GORM without specify any ID.

I try this :

```
func main() {

    db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "...")

    //...
    db.DropTable(&User{})
    db.CreateTable(&User{})
    db.Exec("SET IDENTITY_INSERT users OFF;") <-- this doesn't work

    for _, user := range users {
        db.Create(&user)
    }

}

type User struct {
    ID        uint
    UserName  string
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}

var users []User = []User{
    User{UserName: "testUserName", FirstName: "testFirstName", LastName: "TestLastName"},
    User{UserName: "testUserName", FirstName: "testFirstName", LastName: "TestLastName"},
    User{UserName: "testUserName", FirstName: "testFirstName", LastName: "TestLastName"},
}
```

EDIT :

The data is not create in database, I have the following error (sorry in french) :

```
(mssql: Une valeur explicite doit être spécifiée dans la colonne d'identité de la table 'users' quand IDENTITY_INSERT est défini à ON, ou qu'un utilisateur de la réplication effectue une insertion dans une colonne d'identité NOT FOR REPLICATION.)
```

in en :

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'users' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."
```

The program work if I add the ID value like :

```
User{ID: 1, UserName: "testUserName", FirstName: "testFirstName", LastName: "TestLastName"}
```

Someone have any idea ?

Comment: Can you define "this doesn't work"? What does that mean?

Comment: What does GORM stand for?

Comment: @MisterPositive If you hover over the tag you'll see: `GORM is Grails' object relational mapping (ORM) implementation.`

Comment: @TT LOL, missed the flag.  duh...

Comment: Can you translate the rest of the error message to English?

Comment: `IDENTITY_INSERT` is a per-session setting and it defaults to `OFF`. There should be no need to set it explicitly when you've just opened a connection, as you show here. So, no matter what the current problem is, changing the `IDENTITY_INSERT` setting isn't part of the solution.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to insert an explicit value for the ID column when that column is clearly an IDENTITY column? Values in an identity column are supposed to be generated by the database engine, not by you on the presentation layer.

Comment: @MisterPositive i tried to translate :) , TT i'm just trying to learn how GORM working :) and to follow the documentation :x

Comment: You probably shouldn't do this in our application code. It would be a lot more appropriate to set in a deploy script. Also, isn't that the default behavior on the table? You have id as primary key? Auto increment int?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use a transaction

```
tx := db.Begin()
if err := tx.Exec("SET IDENTITY_INSERT users OFF;").Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
if err := tx.Commit().Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** need to do this, and there are rare cases for this you have to enable this functionality ( to set the value for identity column ) like so

```
Set Identity_Insert dbo.users On
Insert Into users (YOURIDENTITYCOLUMN, NAME)
Values(1, 'your value')
Set Identity_Insert dbo.users Off
```

If your not trying to set the value of the identity column, then remove the statement SET Identity_Insert dbo.users Off portion from your query.

Comment: I did not see the ON part in your code sample above, and the error clearly says Identity_Insert is set to off.

Comment: following https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188059.aspx Identity_Insert have to be Off to insert element WITHOUT a specific ID

Comment: No -- you have to set Identity_Insert On to allow for inserts where you want to specify the value for the identity column, then you disable it by turning it off.  The code included is correct way to insert into a table with Identity column

Comment: it's doesn't work too with the ON value.. :( have the same error