# GORM and SQL Server: auto-incrementation does not work

Tags: sql-server, go, insert, auto-increment, go-gorm

I am trying to insert new value into my SQL Server table using GORM. However, it keeps returning errors. Below you can find detailed example:

```
type MyStructure struct {
    ID                     int32                    `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
    SomeFlag               bool                     `gorm:"not null"`
    Name                   string                   `gorm:"type:varchar(60)"`
}
```

Executing the code below (with Create inside transaction)

```
myStruct := MyStructure{SomeFlag: true, Name: "XYZ"}

result = tx.Create(&myStruct)
    if result.Error != nil {
        return result.Error
    }
```

results in the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'dbo.MyStructures'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

SQL query generated by GORM looks then as follows:

```
INSERT INTO "MyStructures" ("SomeFlag","Name") OUTPUT INSERTED."ID" VALUES (1, 'XYZ')
```

On the other hand, executing Create directly on DB connection (without using transaction) results in the following error:

> Table 'MyStructures' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation

SQL query generated by GORM looks then as follows:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT "MyStructures" ON;INSERT INTO "MyStructures" ("SomeFlag", "Name") OUTPUT INSERTED."ID" VALUES (1, 'XYZ');SET IDENTITY_INSERT "MyStructures" OFF;
```

How can I make the auto-incrementation work in this case?
Why do I get two different errors depending on whether it is inside or outside transaction?

Comment: how you solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this in gorm's issues:

`gorm.DefaultCallback.Create().Remove("mssql:set_identity_insert")`

https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/941#issuecomment-250267125

Comment: /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MyStructures]    Script Date: 8/10/2021 10:13:07 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyStructures](
 [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [SomeFlag] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [Name] [varchar](60),
 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

Comment: "Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'MyStructures' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column"

I haven't changed anything in code.

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40178215/how-to-turn-off-identity-insert-for-gorm

Comment: And I find this in gorm issue: `gorm.DefaultCallback.Create().Remove("mssql:set_identity_insert")`
https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/941#issuecomment-250267125

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your Struct

```
type MyStructure struct {
    ID                     int32                    `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement:true"`
    SomeFlag               bool                     `gorm:"not null"`
    Name                   string                   `gorm:"type:varchar(60)"`
}
```

with this

```
type MyStructure struct {
    ID                     int32                    `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT;PRIMARY_KEY;not null"`
    SomeFlag               bool                     `gorm:"not null"`
    Name                   string                   `gorm:"type:varchar(60)"`
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. i still get following error: mssql: Table 'MyStructures' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to embed the **gorm.Model** in the struct which gives the fields by default: *ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, DeletedAt*. ID will be the primary key by default, and it is auto-incremented (managed by GORM)

```
type MyStructure struct {
    gorm.Model
    SomeFlag               bool                     `gorm:"not null"`
    Name                   string                   `gorm:"type:varchar(60)"`
}
```

Drop the existing table: `db.Migrator().DropTable(&MyStructure{})` and create the table again: `db.AutoMigrate(&MyStructure{})` and then try to insert the record.