# GORM and SQLite : auto increment don't work

Tags: sqlite, go, go-gorm

I have this following struct :

```
// Equipement
type Equipement struct {
   ID int gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement"
   IP string gorm:"not null"
   Username string gorm:"not null"
   AuthPass string gorm:"not null"
   AuthProtocol string gorm:"not null"
   PrivatePass string gorm:"not null"
   PrivateProtocol string gorm:"not null"
}
```

[image: db browser without auto increment]

and I want to put auto increment on my ID.. however I don't have anything when I do AutoMigrate()..

I see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68722871/gorm-and-sql-server-auto-incrementation-does-not-work) but I don't want to use gorm.Model and I want use my own ID.

Next image is what I want..

[image: db browser with auto increment]

Comment: Whats gorm version ? Whats the db/dialect ?

Comment: GORM : v1.21.15 and I use SQLite database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand AutoIncrement it is default when you set PrimaryKey.
Try change autoIncrement to not null.

```
 ID             uint   `gorm:"primaryKey; not null"`
```

https://gorm.io/docs/composite_primary_key.html#content-inner

Comment: This is good, I do it in another computer with same program. Thanks for your time.